# Get windows authenticated user name in .net app?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, windows-authentication

How to get windows authenticated user name in .net application? My app is hosted on IIS. There is no Login form. But, I want to get the windows user name of the persons browsing it. I tried all the request objects. principal object getcurrent().name returns IIS app pool user name. But not the actual user. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: you wont get the user name unless windows auth is on. do you care if a user is ever prompted for login? if want anonymous browsing all the time you cannot get this. see my post below.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot. Unless your application is using windows auth (and they could be prompted at some point like in firefox) you cannot get this information. If you do allow it, then access it via http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.user.aspx

HttpContext.User.Identity.Name

again though - they could be prompted for a login at some point.

Comment: I turned on Windows auth, and now I am using Request objects to get it. Thanks a Ton everyone

Answer (score 1):

You can't unless you enable windows authenication.

Comment: I turned on Windows auth, and now I am using Request objects to get it. Thanks a Ton everyone